# Indirect questions

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

> 1. What kind of food do you think **it** is better to eat for lunch?
> 2. What kind of food do you think is better to eat for lunch?

Do both sentences imply the same thing?

Comment: It might be just me, but #2 sounds a lot more natural.

Comment: Usually the **it** is not used in this kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

The two sentences have different syntactic structures.
The embedded question phrase *What kind of food* is moved to the beginning in each one,
as in all *wh*-questions, but it's moved from a different place in each one.

In the first sentence, with extraposition *it*, the *wh*-phrase is the object of the verb *eat*:

> - *What kind of food do you think **it** is better to eat **...** for lunch?*

In the second sentence, without extraposition, it's the subject of the predicate adjective *is better*:

> - *What kind of food do you think  **...**  is better to eat for lunch?*

As noted -- and as is common with such minimally-differenced sentences -- they have the same meaning. That's because extraposition, like all syntactic transformations, doesn't change meaning.

Comment: This needs to be transferred back to ELU, possibly with the question modified to ask about possible difference in structures.